# MySql select timestamp as datetime

Tags: mysql

How can I select values that are timestamp as date format(that is only with year, month and day values)? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'%Y %D %M');
```

for that it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
select DATE(column) from myTABLE

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(<your timestamp>,'%Y %D %M') AS MYDATE, column1, column2 FROM table;
```